# tabItem in shinydashboard not updating

Tags: shinydashboard

I am new to shinydashboards and trying to get my UI
I have two tabs but the content of both are visible when i run the tab and the content in the body does not change when switching between tabs...

This is a "textbook" example, so I am totally puzzled... i am counting all my brackets which I see is the common issue ... I am stuck!

This is my ui.r and nothing i have the default server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

#--------
#--------
#individual components

#--------
#sidebar

sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("1", tabName="Item1"),
    menuItem("2", tabName="Item2")


  )#sidebarMenu
)#dashboardSidebar

#--------

#body

body<- dashboardBody(
  tabItem(tabName='Item1',
          h2("item1 content")
          ),#tabItem

  tabItem(tabName="Item2",
          h2("item2 content")
          )#tabItem


)#dashboardBody

#--------
#--------
#MAIN

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(

dashboardPage
(
  dashboardHeader(title="hi there"),
  sidebar,
  body

) #dashboardPage

) #shinyUI
```

Answer (score 0):

and mm... stupid me missing.. **tabItems**

```
body<- dashboardBody(
  tabItems( #THIS!!!
  tabItem(tabName='Item1',
          h2("item1 content")
          ),#tabItem

  tabItem(tabName="Item2",
          h2("item2 content")
          )#tabItem

  )#tabItems <- THIS!!!


)#dashboardBody

#--------
#--------
#MAIN

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(

dashboardPage
(
  dashboardHeader(title="hi there"),
  sidebar,
  body

) #dashboardPage

) #shinyUI
```